# What does `o*` mean?

Tags: bash, cpu, shell

Displaying the amount of CPU used at the terminal in% Question is not being understood in the middle of creating a bash script.

```
for x in $(seq 1 11);do sleep 5;grep -w cpu /proc/stat ; done | awk '{
    print (o2+o4-$2-$4)*100/(o2+o4+o5-$2-$4-$5) "%"
    o2=$2;o4=$4;o5=$5}'
```

What does `o2` like `o2, o4, o5` mean?
is silly Question?

Answer (score 2):

They are variables in the `awk` script...
This formatting might make it more clear:

```bsh
for x in $(seq 1 11); do
  sleep 5
  grep -w cpu /proc/stat
done | \
  awk '
    {
      print (o2 + o4 - $2 - $4) * 100 / (o2 + o4 + o5 - $2 - $4 - $5) "%"
      o2=$2
      o4=$4
      o5=$5
    }'
```

You are taking any line that has "cpu" in it from `/proc/stat`:

```bsh
$ grep -w cpu /proc/stat
cpu  737017 2198 503480 221363877 201487 97326 0 0 0 0
```

Doing this every 5 seconds:

```bsh
for x in $(seq 1 11); do
  sleep 5
  grep -w cpu /proc/stat
done
```

And piping the output into `awk`.
`awk` is taking fields 2, 4 and 5 (`$2`, `$4` and `$5`) doing a calculation, and storing them in variables `o2`, `o4`, and `o5`.

```bsh
awk '
    {
      print (o2 + o4 - $2 - $4) * 100 / (o2 + o4 + o5 - $2 - $4 - $5) "%"
      o2=$2
      o4=$4
      o5=$5
    }'
```

---

You can find out more information about `/proc/stat` from the man page, [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

```bsh
/proc/stat
              kernel/system statistics.  Varies with architecture.  Common
              entries include:

              cpu  3357 0 4313 1362393
                     The amount of time, measured in units of USER_HZ
                     (1/100ths of a second on most architectures, use
                     sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) to obtain the right value), that
                     the system spent in various states:

                     [...]

                     nice   (2) Time spent in user mode with low priority
                            (nice).

                     [...]

                     idle   (4) Time spent in the idle task.  This value
                            should be USER_HZ times the second entry in the
                            /proc/uptime pseudo-file.

                     iowait (since Linux 2.5.41)
                            (5) Time waiting for I/O to complete.

                     [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

The o2, o4 and o5 mean nothing. They look like they should be variables, but the variables are set after the calculation. If you want to use a variable, you have to set it before you use it.

Here is a simpler calculation to illustrate the problem. I want to add two numbers.

```
$ echo 6 4 | awk '{ print $1 + $2 }'
10

$ echo 6 4 | awk '{
  print o1 + o2    # print the sum of two numbers using unset variables
  print o1, o2     # print the unset variables
  o1=$1            # set the variables
  o2=$2
  print o1, o2     # print the set variables
  }'
0

6 4
```

awk decides to use 0 to represent the unset value in the calculation.

Looking at the cpu calculation, it essentially does the following:

```
(0 + 0 - x - y) * 100 / (0 + 0 - x - y - z)
```

You end up with a negative number divided by a negative number yielding a positive number.

In this case, the following would have sufficed:

```
$ grep -w cpu /proc/stat | awk '{ print ($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5) "%" }'
```